# Python itertools groupby not grouping as I expect

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

Suppose I have a string like so:

```
st='''Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4

Line 5
Line 6

Line 7
Line 8 
Line 9

Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
Line 13
Line 14'''
# may be really big...
```

Now suppose I want a LoL grouped by the blank lines:

```
[['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3', 'Line 4'],
 ['Line 5', 'Line 6'],
 ['Line 7', 'Line 8 ', 'Line 9'],
 ['Line 10', 'Line 11', 'Line 12', 'Line 13', 'Line 14']]
```

I know that I can create that LoL with a regex split:

```
[[x] for x in re.split(r'^\s*\n',st,flags=re.MULTILINE)]
```

However, I am trying to create this with a non-regex Python generator. The closest I have gotten is this horrible thing (which includes the blanks and is not at all efficient I know...):

```
result=[]        
for sub in (group for key, group in itertools.groupby(st.splitlines(), lambda x: not x.rstrip())):
    result.append(list(sub))

print result
```

Any hints on a direction to go?

I am somewhat keying off [THIS SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10748431/455276).

Comment: By the way, your final loop can be simplified to `[list(group) for _, group in itertools.groupby(st.splitlines(), lambda x: not x.rstrip())]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably write

```
>>> grouped = itertools.groupby(map(str.strip, st.splitlines()), bool)
>>> [list(g) for k,g in grouped if k]
[['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3', 'Line 4'], ['Line 5', 'Line 6'], 
['Line 7', 'Line 8', 'Line 9'], ['Line 10', 'Line 11', 'Line 12', 'Line 13', 'Line 14']]
```

This will also handle blank lines with whitespace, which `\n\n`-based splitting won't.  On the other hand, it doesn't preserve leading and trailing whitespace, which from the `'Line 8 '` example you may want.  If that matters, you could do:

```
grouped = itertools.groupby(st.splitlines(), lambda x: bool(x.strip()))
```

(which, looking at it, is pretty close to what you're already doing.)

Comment: Drak! (headslap) It is the SECOND (`[list(g) for k,g in grouped if k]`) comprehension I was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is there some reason this wouldn't work for you?

```
>>> lol = [group.split("\n") for group in st.split("\n\n")]
>>> pprint(lol)
[['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3', 'Line 4'],
 ['Line 5', 'Line 6'],
 ['Line 7', 'Line 8 ', 'Line 9'],
 ['Line 10', 'Line 11', 'Line 12', 'Line 13', 'Line 14']]
```

Comment: This is great (+1) but what I was hoping for is a kinda general pupose generator. See edit of question.